# bash4 read file into associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, file, associative

I am able to read file into a regular array with a single statement:

```
local -a ary
readarray -t ary < $fileName
```

Not happening is reading a file into assoc. array.

I have control over file creation and so would like to do as simply as possible w/o loops if possible at all.

So file content can be following to be read in as:

```
keyname=valueInfo
```

But I am willing to replace = with another string if cuts down on code, especially in a single line code as above.

#### And ...

So would it be possible to read such a file into an assoc array using something like an `until`  or `from` - i.e. read into an assoc array until it hits a word, or would I have to do this as part of loop?

This will allow me to keep a lot of similar values in same file, but read into separate arrays.

I looked at `mapfile` as well, but does same as `readarray`.

#### Finally ...

I am creating an options list - to select from - as below:

```
local -a arr=("${!1}")
select option in ${arr[*]}; do
    echo ${option}
    break
done
```

Works fine - however the list shown is not sorted. I would like to have it sorted if possible at all.

Hope it is ok to put all 3 questions into 1 as the questions are similar - all on arrays.

Thank you.

Comment: I'll ask this because I always do: are you sure you want to use bash for this? I find for any real logic, it's often worth it to delegate to ruby, python, or another richer scripting language.

Comment: @JordanSamuels So far I see that most of it can be essentially done in Bash.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First thing, associative arrays are declared with `-A` not `-a`:

```
local -A ary
```

And if you want to declare a variable on global scope, use `declare` outside of a function:

```
declare -A ary
```

Or use `-g` if `BASH_VERSION >= 4.2`.

If your lines do have `keyname=valueInfo`, with `readarray`, you can process it like this:

```
readarray -t lines < "$fileName"

for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
   key=${line%%=*}
   value=${line#*=}
   ary[$key]=$value  ## Or simply ary[${line%%=*}]=${line#*=}
done
```

Using a `while read` loop can also be an option:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ary[${line%%=*}]=${line#*=}
done < "$fileName"
```

Or

```
while IFS== read -r key value; do
    ary[$key]=$value
done < "$fileName"
```

Comment: konsolebox - Just wanted to say thanks! All the code worked out really well. Finally finished implementing!

Comment: I think `${line...` should be quoted like `"${line..."`. Similarly `$key` should be `"$key"` and `$value` s/b `"$value"`. Still upvoted and I'll try this code in current project. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's not necessary in those instances because filename expansion and .word splitting don't happen.

Comment: Yes. I actually ditched the technique for this project because bash put `\` in front of every space. I went with normal array for data fields and associative array with key and value as index number to data array.